# FreeBSD rc.d script doesn't start as a daemon

Tags: freebsd, shell-scripting, rc.d

I have developed the following script at location `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/bluesky`

```
#!/bin/sh

# PROVIDE: bluesky
# REQUIRE: mysql sshd
# BEFORE:  
# KEYWORD: 

. /etc/rc.subr

name="bluesky"
rcvar=bluesky_enable

start_cmd="${name}_start"
stop_cmd=":"

load_rc_config $name
: ${bluesky_enable:=no}
: ${bluesky_msg="HTTP server starts ..."}

bluesky_start(){
    echo $PATH
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/
    echo $PATH

    ### Run Node server ###
    /usr/local/bin/node /usr/home/ict/Documents/bluesky/server.js
    echo "$bluesky_msg"
}

run_rc_command "$1"
```

I also have enabled it on my `/etc/rc.conf` file:

```
bluesky_enable="YES"
```

---

When I reboot the server, the script works fine and starts the HTTP server at port 80. The only problem is that the script won't be sent to background or won't be started as a daemon. I wonder how I can run script at boot time in the **background** or as a **daemon**.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The RC script itself is not intended to daemonize, but is expected to start and stop the daemon.

If your service does not have an option to start as a daemon, you can use [daemon(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=daemon) to manage that part.

An example:

```
#!/bin/sh

# PROVIDE: ...
# REQUIRE: ...

. /etc/rc.subr

name="..."

rcvar=${name}_enable
pidfile="/var/run/${name}.pid"
command="/usr/sbin/daemon"
command_args="-c -f -P ${pidfile} -r /usr/local/libexec/${name}"
load_rc_config $name
run_rc_command "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD terminal I installed [PM2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4018154/3405291):

```
$ sudo npm install pm2 -g
```

and then modified the `rc.d` script according to `pm2`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# PROVIDE: bluesky
# REQUIRE: mysql sshd
# BEFORE:  
# KEYWORD: 

. /etc/rc.subr

name="bluesky"
rcvar=bluesky_enable

start_cmd="${name}_start"
stop_cmd=":"

load_rc_config $name
: ${bluesky_enable:=no}
: ${bluesky_msg="HTTP server starts ..."}

bluesky_start(){
    echo $PATH
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/
    echo $PATH

    ### Start server with PM2 ###
    /usr/local/bin/pm2 start /usr/home/ict/Documents/bluesky/server.js
    echo "$bluesky_msg"
}

run_rc_command "$1"
```

---

Now, the HTTP server is started as a daemon at boot time. However I really like the idea of FreeBSD [daemon(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=daemon) suggested by @RichardSmith, I'm going to work on it.